# How to get a subset of objects in an array passing an array as an argument

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am receiving an array of objects as response data from an API call.

```
data = [{obj1},{obj2},{obj3},{obj4},{obj5}]

obj1 = {
  prop1: 'value1',
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: 'value3',
}
```

I am trying to use an array, let's say: ['prop2', 'prop3'] to filter the array of objects and return an array of a subset of objects.

```
[{filteredObj1},{filteredObj2},{filteredObj3},{filteredObj4},{filteredObj5}]

filteredObj1 = {
  prop2: 'value2',
  prop3: 'value3'
}
```

And so on...

In have tried the following approach initially:

```
const arrayOfPropsIWant = ['prop1', 'prop2']

data.forEach((el) => {
  const filtered = (({ ...arrayOfPropsIWant }) => ({ ...arrayOfPropsIWant }))(el);
})
```

This worked when instead of passing the ...arrayOfPropsIWant to destructure I passed the props explicitly (({ prop1, prop2 })

I am trying to build a custom ReactJS hook, is there a way I can achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use Array.map:

```
const data = [
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3' },
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'},
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'}
]

const arrayOfPropsIWant = ['prop1', 'prop2']

const filtered = data.map((elem) => {
    const out = {};
    arrayOfPropsIWant.forEach(prop => out[prop] = elem[prop]);
    return out;
   }
);

console.log(filtered);
```

Answer (score 1):

try  with [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map)

```js
const data = [
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3' },
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'},
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'}
]

const result = data.map(({prop2, prop3})=>({prop2, prop3}))

console.log(result);
```

Comment: You cant edit the prop names with a string array in that example

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

```js
const data = [
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3' },
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'},
 { prop1: 'value1', prop2: 'value2', prop3: 'value3'}
];

const props=['prop1','prop2']

const result = data.map((item)=>{
  Object.keys(item).map((key)=>{
    if(!props.includes(key))
      delete item[key];
  })
  return item;
})

console.log(result);
```

Comment: The delete fully deletes the object attribute, what if you need them later? You should do a copy of the object first.

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```js
const data = [
  { name: 'aaa', age: 10, id: 1 },
  { name: 'aab', age: 20, id: 2 },
];

const map = array => keys =>
  array.map(
    /** you should use 
    Object.fromEntries(
      Object.entries(item).filter(([key])=>keys.includes(key))
    )
    but beause Stack Overflow has not updated babel since years
    this will not work on SO code snippet
    **/
    item =>
      keys.reduce((result, key) => {
        result[key] = item[key];
        return result;
      }, {})
  );
const mapData = map(data);
console.log('id and name', mapData(['id', 'name']));
console.log('id and age', mapData(['id', 'age']));
```